# "to appear in the dock on"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm new here. This is my first question. What's the meaning of the sentence with italic/bold. I'm writing complete passage to make simpler.

> He was described by prosecuting lawyers as the alleged "ringmaster" of efforts to manipulate the benchmark inter-bank interest rate. He pleaded not guilty to eight charges of conspiracy to defraud. It is the first time ***someone has appeared in the dock on*** LIBOR charges.

Comment: has appeared in the dock = has been on trial (in court) // on LIBOR charges = accused of rigging the London Interbank Offered Rate (almost certainly).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth has it right. One [definition of "*dock*"](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Dock&ls=a) is "*noun:  an enclosure in a court of law where the defendant sits during the trial*", and here it's clearly being used as a metonym for "*court*", or, figuratively, *trial*.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's short for [docket](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=docket&use1828=on), which [Noah Websters' 1828 American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/) defines several ways. In this context it probably means:

> 3. An alphabetical list of cases in a court, or a catalogue of the names of the parties who have suits depending in a court. In some of the states, this is the principal or only use of the word.

Just to reiterate its the first time anybody was on the list to appear in this court for that particular type of crime.